# Want to create a middle bar between two columns and add functionality like increase and decrease width depending on the mouse left and right move

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

You can see the example from this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_test) of w3 school where the width of two columns adjusts depending on the mouse left and right movement. I want to apply this functionality in my react app but don't know how to do that.
[image]

my jsx code:

```
... return(
<>
    Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={3} style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                Column 1
              </Col> //here Want to create a middle bar between two columns and add functionality like increase and decrease width depending on the mouse left and right move.
              <Col style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>column 2</Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
</>
)
```

I tried this

```
const admin = () => {
  const [leftColumnWidth, setLeftColumnWidth] = useState(3); // Initial width for left column
  const [isResizing, setIsResizing] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    setIsResizing(true);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsResizing(false);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!isResizing) return;

    const containerWidth = e.currentTarget.offsetWidth;
    const mouseX = e.clientX;
    const newLeftColumnWidth = Math.min(
      Math.max((mouseX / containerWidth) * 100, 10), // Minimum width 10%
      90 // Maximum width 90%
    );

    setLeftColumnWidth(newLeftColumnWidth);
  };
  return (
    <>  <Container fluid onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
        <Row>
          <Col
            xs={leftColumnWidth}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "red",
              borderRight: "1px solid black",
              height: "100vh",
              overflow: "hidden",
            }}
          >
            1 of 3
            <div
              style={{
                width: "10px",
                cursor: "col-resize",
                position: "absolute",
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
              }}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            ></div>
          </Col>
          <Col style={{ backgroundColor: "black", height: "100vh" }}>
            2 of 3 (wider)
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>  );
};
```

but not working see the result [image]

khurram shafique answer working but also want to know how to do it B and C section also [image]
my updated code for A B C section :

```
 <div
        ref={containerRef}
        style={{ display: "flex", height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: `${columnWidth}%`,
            background: "lightgrey",
            overflow: "auto", // Enable scrollbar when content exceeds height
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ height: "500px", padding: "16px" }}>Column A</div>
        </div>
        <div
          ref={handleRef}
          onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
          style={{ cursor: "ew-resize", width: "10px", background: "grey" }}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            width: `${100 - columnWidth}%`,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              background: "lightblue",
              overflow: "auto", // Enable scrollbar when content exceeds height
              flex: "70%", // 70% of the available space
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ height: "300px", padding: "16px" }}>Section B</div>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              background: "lightgreen",
              height: "30%", // 30% of the available space
              overflow: "auto", // Enable scrollbar when content exceeds height
            }}
          >
            Section C
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you given anything a try?

Comment: @Sean I updated my question and tried but not working like w3 school

Comment: A simple `View Source` on that page followed by searching for `dragbar`, `dragging`, `dragmove` will tell you all you need to know. Just copy it.

Comment: You are looking for a 'splitter'. Checkout [codepen search](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=splitter)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React what Framework you are using , Bootstrap, Tailwind or martial UI, and I am giving you generic code which you can use according to your situation

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

function ResizableColumns() {
  const [columnWidth, setColumnWidth] = useState(50); // Starting width percentage for column A
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const handleRef = useRef(null);

  const onMouseDown = () => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  };

  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    // Calculate the percentage width of column A
    const containerRect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const newWidth = ((e.clientX - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width) * 100;

    // Update the state with the new width, making sure it stays within bounds
    setColumnWidth(Math.min(100, Math.max(0, newWidth)));
  };

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} style={{ display: "flex", height: "200px", width: "100%" }}>
      <div style={{ width: `${columnWidth}%`, background: "lightgrey", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        Column A
      </div>
      <div
        ref={handleRef}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        style={{ cursor: "ew-resize", width: "10px", background: "grey" }}
      />
      <div style={{ width: `${100 - columnWidth}%`, background: "lightblue", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        Column B
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ResizableColumns;
```

Comment: Thanks working. would be better if add some description in your code of how it's working. also want to give default width how to do that?

Comment: Using the useState and useRef hooks    and for State, initially define the column width 50% using the useState hook and than mouseOver Function defines the mouses envent, e useRef hook to create references to the container and the handle between the columns. This will help us calculate widths later. Mouse move and mouseDown handler to handle the even of mouse, and last return to render this code , its straightforward

Comment: how to use it also between section B and C see the screenshot and also see my updated answer https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qu92PTVoXTOgGemgmLyUZxt_f12O0M53/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

here is the Rendering part where you have return so you just need to add rows in colum be so now you are dividing column in two or as many rows as you want .

```js
 return (
    <div ref={containerRef} style={{ display: "flex", height: "200px", width: "100%" }}>
      <div style={{ width: `${columnWidth}%`, background: "lightgrey", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        Column A
      </div>
      <div
        ref={handleRef}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        style={{ cursor: "ew-resize", width: "10px", background: "grey" }}
      />
      <div style={{ width: `${100 - columnWidth}%`, background: "lightblue", overflow: "hidden", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <div style={{ flex: 1, background: "pink", overflow: "hidden" }}>
          Row B1
        </div>
        <div style={{ flex: 1, background: "yellow", overflow: "hidden" }}>
          Row B2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: khurram shafique section A and B  width adjusting on mouse movement but B  and C hight not adjusting

Comment: Please edit your original answer instead of posting an additional one